# Emacs switch to upper or left windows

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to speed up when switching between different windows - sometimes `C-x-o` is just too slow when I have multiple windows. Say, I have 4 windows now, and I want to switch to the upper one by `C-x-up arrow`, to the left by `C-x-left arrow,` to the bottom by `C-x-down arrow`, to the right by `C-x-right arrow`. How should I code in .emacs?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

The [`windmove`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WindMove) package is designed for this.

By default, you can switch windows using <kbd>Shift</kbd> with the arrow keys. As outlined in the linked post, simply

```lisp
(when (fboundp 'windmove-default-keybindings)
  (windmove-default-keybindings))
```

Of course, this is fully configurable. For instance, I bind it to the arrow keys without any modifier (I already use `C-p`, `C-n`, etc. for movement) like this:

```lisp
(when (locate-library "windmove")
  (global-set-key (kbd "<left>") 'windmove-left)
  (global-set-key (kbd "<right>") 'windmove-right)
  (global-set-key (kbd "<up>") 'windmove-up)
  (global-set-key (kbd "<down>") 'windmove-down))
```

`windmove` is shipped with Emacs.

Comment: The windmove commands are all autoloaded by default nowadays, so the bindings are all you need.

Comment: Also, an `if` with no *else* condition can be written as a `when`, and then you don't need the `progn` :)

Comment: @phils, both good points. I have updated my own configuration, and my answer, accordingly.

Comment: The default works terrific!

Comment: Well the later one - do I just need to copy and paste? Cuz it didn't work, I guess I need some revisions, but I'm really novice to Emacs languages.. Anyways the default settings works elegantly. Thanks very much!

Comment: @Twinkle, you may need to `autoload` the functions, depending on your version of Emacs. I had a [slightly different version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20942342/1) up originally. Try that if you've got something older than, say, 24.3.

Comment: @Chris Thanks very much I think mine has windmove loaded. I just realized that I forgot  to add C-x in the front, so now it works as my original idea. Terrific!

Answer (score 0):

This is my final answer and it works elegantly! This is the first time I defined shortcuts myself in Emacs. Terrific! Thanks very much @Chris!

```
(when (locate-library "windmove")
    (global-set-key (kbd "C-x <left>") 'windmove-left)
    (global-set-key (kbd "C-x <right>") 'windmove-right)
    (global-set-key (kbd "C-x <up>") 'windmove-up)
    (global-set-key (kbd "C-x <down>") 'windmove-down)
  )
```

PS my windmove package is autoloaded.

Comment: Be sure to 'accept' Chris' answer (as your own answer is essentially identical).